# Не получается скопировать файл

Tags: php, laravel

Код находится в файле HomeController.php

```
        copy("/users/test_img.jpg", "/users/test3.jpg");
```

Директории:

```
project
       app
          http
              controllers
                         HomeController.php
       users
            test_img.jpg
```

После запуска получаю такую ошибку:

```
copy(/users/test_img.jpg): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Потому что Вы пытаетесь копировать с корня системы, а не с корня проекта.

Answer (score 4):

Перед тем как учить ларавель и пхп, надо освоить основы компьютерной грамотности. И в частности то, как обращаться к файлам на диске. Вот эта косая палочка, `/`, означает не "дорогой компьютер, догадайся сам, куда я хочу записать файлик", а совершенно конкретный адрес - корень диска. И в корне диска, разумеется, никакой папки users нет.

Вместо этого надо указывать **правильный абсолютный путь к папке от корня диска**. Причем в ларавле есть специальные средства, чтобы получить путь до приложения, на основе которого уже достраивать путь к своему файлу. Например, функция `base_path()`.

Но в данном случае, поскольку речь идет пользовательских файлах, записывать надо не в какую-то левую папку users, а использовать компонент [Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#copying-moving-files)

Comment: За функцию спасибо, не знал про нее